# Printf its variations and its prototype understanding

Tags: c, printf

Can anybody explain the variations in printf syntax..i am confused in some of it
like

```
 printf(5+"hello my friend");//i have problem this addition of 5 
 printf("hello""my""friend");//i have problem with double apostrophe
```

what kind of printf prototype do these follows ?
Is this have anything to do with dynamic linking?
Can anybody show some other weird printfs and explain them.

Comment: You really have no idea what you are doing. (Prototypes? Dynamic linking? What gives?) Before trying to be clever, just read a good beginner C tutorial.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Actually, both calls are perfectly legal.

Comment: You need to learn how strings work.

Comment: Read the question to the right under `Linked` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a?lq=1

Comment: @H2CO3:- Yes I knew that. I was about to update the same but before that I got the downvotes!!!

Comment: @RahulTripathi You can still edit an undelete your question in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string in C is accessed via a pointer to a `char` (see H2CO3's comment for a more precise definition). If you add `5` to a pointer to a `char`, you start the string 5 characters later. So `5+"hello my friend"` points to `" my friend"`, skipping `"hello"`.

When a C compiler sees two strings with nothing (except possibly whitespace) in between, it treats them as a single string. This makes it easier to break long strings in multiple lines. 
So `"hello""my""friend"` compiles into exactly the same thing as `"hellomyfriend"` or

```
"hello"
"my"
"friend"
```

None of these has anything to do with `printf`, and a lot to do with strings.

Comment: A string in C is not a pointer to char. It's an array of `char` that decays into a pointer to its first element in certain contexts.

Comment: i usually forget some of the rules of c everyday.